# How to consider the effect of margin call risk in a gamma scalping strategy

Tags: options, volatility, margin, option-strategies

I am trying to tippy toe into volatility trading and volatility strategies.

So I was reading Sheldon Natenberg where he starts off with a portfolio of long ATM call and short 50 shares of stock to set up a delta neutral position.

Now if stock goes up (let us say 5%), he shorts additional shares to become delta neutral again.

My question is, how do margin calls feature into this? if the stock goes up a certain amount, my initial short position is in risk of margin call(being auto liquidated). This risk becomes increasingly prominent as I keep selling all the way up, to maintain my flat position.How can I factor in this risk while evaluating this strategy?

Let us assume that both initial and maintenance margin is 30% and I utilized maximum margin while opening the trade.

Comment: a margin call does not "liquidate your trade" it means that you have to post more margin against the security as the margin requirement has risen

Comment: Broker dependent. Interactive brokers don't call you, they just close positions if they violate maintenance margin.

Comment: you're forgetting your calls would increase in price somewhat as you lose money on your shorts.  should offset some of your "losses" on the short side preventing a margin call.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not think of that.

Comment: Have a read here, might explain things better.  Then lookup 'UCO' stock for the past 30 days.   Would have been a great gamma play.  https://www.randomwalktrading.com/practical-gamma-scalping/

Comment: Thanks, I need to build some kind of scanner so I don't miss these opportunities.

Comment: In the example, why did they start off with a straddle as opposed to a delta neutral position like long ATM call and short 50 shares of IBM. Straddle has a big capital cost upfront.

Comment: If the upfront costs seem excessive, maybe you are investing too large a percentage of your assets.  1% is a good number.

Comment: 1% of 50,000 will be 500, so I guess I need to accumulate a bigger bankroll before gamma scalping?